# LED to blink when a push button is NOT pressed and to be continually on when the button IS pressed (Python)

Tags: python, button, tkinter, light

So, i have a LED controlled by a Raspy, and also a basic GUI with just a push button, I want it to behave as follows:

- LED blinks when the push button IS NOT pressed.
- LED should stay ON continually when the push button IS pressed.

When I execute light starts blinking, but **the button does not show up.**
When I interrupt the program, the button shows up. Why?

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(8, False)
buttonPressed = False

master = Tk()

def callback():
    GPIO.output(8, True)
    buttonPressed = True

w = Button(master, text="Turn on light", command = callback)
w.pack()

while True:
    if buttonPressed == False:
        GPIO.output(8, True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(8, False)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        GPIO.output(8, True)
```

Comment: tkinter needs `master.mainloop()` to work. And you shouldn't use any other loop in code because it blocks `mainloop()`, The same with `sleep()` - it blocks mainloop and it can't work correctly. Every GUI framework has some method to run function with delay without blocking mainloop and you can use it instead of `sleep` and to repeate some code without using `while`-loop. Tkinter has `master.after(millisecond, function)`

Comment: BTW: button using command= can recognize  only when button was pressed but it can't recognize if it is still presssed and if it was released. But Tkinter (like any other GUI) has `event` which you can use to run function when you press and releas button.

Comment: most GUI framework use only one thread so they can't do two things at the same time - they can't control if you pressed button (to run command=) and run `while` loop at the same time.

Comment: if in function you want to assign value to external variable then you have to use `global buttonPressed`. If you don't use `global` then function create local variable `buttonPressed` and assing value to this local variable `buttonPressed` - and it doesn't change external variable `buttonPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it on RPi but I could be something like this.

Normal `command=` can recognize only when you clicked button but it can't recognize when you released it - you need to bind events `<ButtonPress>` and `<ButtonRelease>` which will run functions on `"mouse left button press"` and `"mouse left button release"`

I use `after()` to run function with delay so I don't need `sleep()` and `while` which can block `mainloop()` (and it can freeze all GUI).

And I don't need also `while` loop because I run all inside `on_press` and `on_release` and later `after()` runs `turn_off_led` which use `after()` to run `turn_on_led` which use `after()` to run again `turn_off_led` so it works like loop.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(8, False)

button_pressed = False  # PEP8: preferred `lower_case_names`

# --- functions ---

def on_press(event):
    global button_pressed

    button_pressed = True
    GPIO.output(8, True)

def on_release(event):
    global button_pressed

    button_pressed = False
    GPIO.output(8, True)

    # run after 500ms (0.5s) instead of `sleep`
    master.after(500, blink_off)

def blink_off():
    if not button_pressed:
        GPIO.output(8, False)
        # run after 500ms (0.5s) instead of `sleep`
        master.after(500, blink_on)

def blink_on():
    if not button_pressed:
        GPIO.output(8, True)
        # run after 500ms (0.5s) instead of `sleep`
        master.after(500, blink_off)

# --- main ---

master = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(master, text="Turn on light")
button.pack()

# here "button" means "tk.Button" and "Button" means "mouse left button"
button.bind('<ButtonPress>',   on_press)   # mouse left button pressed on tk.Button 
button.bind('<ButtonRelease>', on_release) # mouse left button released on tk.Button

# start blinking - it will use `after()` to loop
blink_on()

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that @furas has you set in the right direction, but since I was working on it for the fun of it I thought I would leave my solution here as well. I pulled out the GPIO code so that I could run it locally.

A key feature of both solutions is that we've removed the calls to `time.sleep`, because when you're `time.sleep`ing, Tk's event loop isn't able to process any events (which would manifest as the UI appearing to "freeze" during those sleep statements).

```
import time
import tkinter

buttonpressed = False
lastchange = 0
ledstate = False

def button_down(event):
    global buttonpressed
    print('BUTTON DOWN')
    buttonpressed = True


def button_up(event):
    global buttonpressed
    print('BUTTON UP')
    buttonpressed = False


def myloop(master):
    global buttonpressed
    global lastchange
    global ledstate

    now = time.time()
    delta = now - lastchange

    if not buttonpressed:
        if now - lastchange > 0.5:
            ledstate = not ledstate
            print('LED', ledstate)
            lastchange = now
    else:
        if not ledstate:
            ledstate = True
            print('LED', ledstate)

    master.after_idle(myloop, master)


master = tkinter.Tk()
w = tkinter.Button(master, text="Turn on light")
w.bind('<ButtonPress>', button_down)
w.bind('<ButtonRelease>', button_up)
w.pack()

master.after(100, myloop, master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: before I start reducing code in my version it was very similar to your version :) I had something like `myloop` with `after` at the end and I was using something like `ledstate`. And I was also thinking to use time to control blinks. Your version can be more readable for beginner - it is more similar to OP code.

Answer (score 3):

A `tkinter` application needs to call `.mainloop()`.

Also you should use `.after(...)` function to simulate the while loop:

```
import tkinter as tk
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def led_on(state):
    global button_pressed
    button_pressed = state

def blink_led(state=True):
    # turn on LED if either state or button_pressed is True
    GPIO.output(8, state or button_pressed)
    master.after(500, blink_led, not state) # toggle the state half a second later

# setup the RPi board
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(8, False)

button_pressed = False

master = tk.Tk()

w = tk.Button(master, text='Turn on light')
w.pack()

w.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda e: led_on(True))  # set button_pressed to True
w.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: led_on(False)) # set button_pressed to False

blink_led()  # start the LED blinking

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I like idea `state or button_pressed` - it reduce code a lot (comparing to my version)